# Concatenacion del texto que ingrese el usuario en un TextFormField y mostrarlo dentro de widget UserAccountsDrawerHeader en Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentado mostrar el texto que el usuario ingrese en un texFormField dentro del widget UserAccountsDrawerHeader, es decir, en  el menuDrawer debe aparecer el texto que el usuario ingrese en un TextFormField utilizando TextEditingController, y hacer como una concatenacion de la palabra Hola + el texto que el usuario agregue.
El nameController, se encuentra en otro archivo.dart que es como el login, en donde el usuario se regitra insertando ahi, el el textFormField relacionado a nameController, Aqui la idea es, que el usuario ingresa su nombre, y que el nombre quede grabado en la parte superior del menuDrawer, seria como una concatenacion, que diga por ejemplo Hola + Texto que el usuario ingrese.

Agrego la parte de textFormField, el cual contiene nameController.

```
  child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Ingresa el nombre de usuario';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
         
                
                  hintText: "Ingrese su Nombre",
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Agrego código del menuDrawer

```
 children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
         

            accountName: Text("Hola:$(nameController.toString())"),
            //accountName: Text("Nombre ${nameController.text}");
        
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.blue,
       
          ),
          Ink(
            color: Colors.green[300],
            child: new ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.blue),
              title: Text(
                "Perfil",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.green),
          new ListTile(
            dense:true,
            focusColor:  Colors.yellow,
            title: const Text("Inicio",
            //style: styleDrawer,
            ),
            leading:  Icon(Icons.home, color:Colors.blue),
            
            onTap: () {
              print("Hola");
            },
            onLongPress: () {
              print('longPress');
            },
          ),
        ....  
      
        ],
```

intentado setear el nombre usuario  mediante FutureBuilder:
Clase para almacenar las variables.

```
class Preferences{
   Future<void> guardarNombre(String nombre) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString('nombre', nombre);

Future<String?> obtenerNombre() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? nombre = preferences.getString('nombre');
    return nombre;
  }
  }
  }
```

En efecto, se tiene un boton, el cual toma el valor, entonces al botón se le agrega FutureBuilder, para llamar al metodo y guardar el nombre

```
Widget botonContinuar() {
final preferences = Preferences();
 return ElevatedButton(onPressed:() {
  preferences.guardarNombre(nameController.text);


  }, 
 child: Text('Continuar'),
  
 
 );
  }
```

Luego vamos al menu Drawer, y a la propiedad accountName, se le agrega FutureBuilder, para que tome el valo que se almacena, eldetalle es que en accountName, marca errro en FutureBuilder y preference

```
 new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
             accountName:   FutureBuilder(//Marca error en FutureBuilder
       future: preferences.obtenerNombre();// Marca error en preference
       builder: (builder, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
           final nombre = snapshot.data;
           return Text(nombre);
           } else{
            return Text('Cargando...')
          }
        }
        
        ),
        accountEmail: Text("informes@gmail.com"),
```

Comment: Agrega más info, en que parte está tu `nameControler`? puedes poner el widget que contiene el UserAccountsDrawerHeader?

Comment: Hola, edite la pregunta añadiendo un poco mas de información.

Comment: Bueno una forma sencilla seria asi: 1) Has que tu Drawer sea un widget independiente, asi tandras accesos a un metodo build y este se llamara cada que abras el drawer. 2) Guarda el resultado de tu TextFormField dentro de las SharedPreferences.
3) Ahora usa un future builder dentro del Drawer que lea el valor que guardaste en el shared preferences y asi determinar si mostrar algo o no. Y listo, para este caso creo seria un forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que utilices SharedPreferences:

```
shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
```

Luego puedes crear una clase de SharedPereferences donde creas los métodos para almacenar las variables:

```
class Preferencias{
   Future<void> guardarNombre(String nombre) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString('nombre', nombre);

Future<String?> obtenerNombre() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? nombre = preferences.getString('nombre');
    return nombre;
  }
```

}

Supongo que para manejar la parte del `NameController` usas un botón para guardar o para setear el valor en el Menú lateral, entonces en este botón donde asignas el valor, vas a llamar al método que tienes en la clase Preferencias:

```
Widget botonContinuar(){
 final preferences = Preferences();
 return RaisedButton(onPressed:() {
  preferences.guardarNombre(NameController.text)
  }, 
 child: Text('Continuar'),);
}
```

Una vez que tu ya tienes guardado el nombre del usuario en el método de `SharedPreferences` vas a hacer lo siguiente en el Menú lateral. En la propiedad `accountName` vas a usar un FutureBuilder para llamar al método `obtenerNombre` de la clase Preferences:

```
children: <Widget>[
      new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: FutureBuilder(
       future: preferences.obtenerNombre();
       builder: (builder, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
           final nombre = snapshot.data;
           return Text(nombre);
           } else{
            return Text('Cargando...')
          }
        }),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.blue,
   
      ),
      Ink(
        color: Colors.green[300],
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.blue),
          title: Text(
            "Perfil",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Divider(color: Colors.green),
      new ListTile(
        dense:true,
        focusColor:  Colors.yellow,
        title: const Text("Inicio",
        //style: styleDrawer,
        ),
        leading:  Icon(Icons.home, color:Colors.blue),
        
        onTap: () {
          print("Hola");
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          print('longPress');
        },
      ),
    ....  
  
    ],
```

Así cada vez que el usuario cierre la aplicación y la vuelva a abrir mostrará directamente el nombre sin necesidad de tener que volver a escribir su nombre en el textField.

//RESPUESTA CORTA:

Si tu aplicación cada que se inicia abre la pantalla donde el usuario tiene que ingresar su nombre puedes pasar el parámetro entre pantallas, aquí te dejo un link donde explican detalladamente:

[Pasar parámetros entre pantallas](https://esflutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Comment: Estoy intentando seguir los pasos, pero al usar FutureBuilder en accountName, arroja un error`   children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
             accountName:   FutureBuilder( //Error en FutireBuilder
       future: preferences.obtenerNombre(); //Marca error en preferences
       builder: (builder, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
           final nombre = snapshot.data;
           return Text(nombre);
           } else{
            return Text('Cargando...')
          }
        }
        
        ),......`

Comment: Seguí los pasos que mencionaste, todo va bien, hasta cuando llego a la propiedad accountName para llamar al método de obtenerNombre, pero marca un error en FutureBuilder, y en preference 
```     accountName:   FutureBuilder(
       future: preferences.obtenerNombre();
       builder: (builder, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
           final nombre = snapshot.data;
           return Text(nombre);
           } else{
            return Text('Cargando...')
          }
        }
        
        ),```

Comment: Que error te bota? Puedes intentar poniendo en el builder esto: (builder, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) y en el return Text(nombre) ponle esto: return Text(nombre ?? '');

Comment: Bien, en el builder ya no hay error, ahora queda en "preferences", arroja el siguiente error ``` : Error: The getter 'preferences' isn't defined for the class 'MenuLateral'.

- 'MenuLateral' is from 'package:cookmenu/menuDrawer.dart' ('lib/menuDrawer.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'preferences'.

       future: preferences.obtenerNombre(),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```     @Jonathan Perez

Comment: Claro, es que en un principio tienes que crear una instancia de la clase Preferencias en mi caso, no se que nombre le habrás puesto a la clase donde defines los métodos para guardar el nombre, en mi caso es Preferencias. En la clase MenuLateral, antes del método build tienes que crear la instancia: final preferences = Preferencias();

Comment: Si, ya esta la instancia para Preferencias, que es el nombre de la clase donde se almacenan los métodos, ahora, en la clase Preferencias, notamos que el metodo obtenerNombre no ha sido reconocido, porque aparece el siguiente error. ```
: Error: The method 'obtenerNombre' isn't defined for the class 'Preferencias'.

- 'Preferencias' is from 'package:cookmenu/menuDrawer.dart' ('lib/menuDrawer.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'obtenerNombre'.
              future: preferences.obtenerNombre(),
 ```

Comment: Puedes unirte a esta sala? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135054/flutter

Comment: Si,   si puedo. ya estoy

Comment: necesito tener 20 de rep, para hablar en el chat

Comment: Es que en ese caso no sabría de que otra manera ayudarte